# How to elegantly modify all elements in a container in-place?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, stl, containers

```
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    A() = default;

    void Add()
    {
        a++;
    }

private:
    int a;
};

int main()
{
    vector<A> x(10);
    for (auto pos = x.begin(); pos != x.end(); ++pos) pos->Add();
}
```

`for_each` seems non-modifying. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each

> f     -   function object, to be applied to the result of dereferencing
>   every iterator in the range [first, last)
>
> The signature of the function should be equivalent to the following:
>
> void fun(const Type &a);
>
> The signature does not need to have const &. The type Type must be
>   such that an object of type InputIt can be dereferenced and then
>   implicitly converted to Type.

So, my question is:

Is there a standard function/way to do the same as `for (auto pos = x.begin(); pos != x.end(); ++pos) pos->Add();` does?

Comment: In fact, `for_each` is modifing.

Comment: Read the page you have linked to the end. There is an example.

Comment: Quoting from that page **If InputIt is a mutable iterator, f may modify the elements of the range through the dereferenced iterator.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use

```
for(auto& p : x) p.Add();
```

this code simple and elegant but is also quite efficient as it allows the compiler to see directly the action without interposing extra logic. Less typing, faster compiling, no nonsense screenfuls of babbling when making typos.

For example the code generated by g++ for

```
for (auto& y : x) {
    y++;
}
```

where `x` is declared as an `std::vector<int>` has an inner loop like

```
.L8:
    movdqa  (%rdi,%rax), %xmm0
    addq    $1, %rdx
    paddd   %xmm1, %xmm0
    movaps  %xmm0, (%rdi,%rax)
    addq    $16, %rax
    cmpq    %rdx, %r8
    ja  .L8
```

where 4 integers are incremented at each iteration using mmx instructions.

Comment: for me it is the best way. However, the OP need standard function

Comment: In many benchmarks that I have seen, `for_each` is slightly faster than `for(auto& p : x)`

Comment: @AlexLop.: No idea which tests you are talking about. A direct `for` on the references allows the compiler to see everything directly. `for_each` can get, when lucky, to the same by peeling off all the machinery and inlining the lambda... but there is no reason for which it should be better. See edit for an example of the generated code.

Answer (score 10):

Not sure why you write that

> for_each is non-modifying

this works just fine:

```
for_each(begin(x), end(x), [](int &i){++i;});
```

for a `vector` of integers, e.g.

Answer (score 3):

`std::for_each` is acutely what are you looking for:

```
std::for_each(std::begin(x),std::end(x),[](A& item){item.add();});
```

However, [6502](https://stackoverflow.com/users/320726/6502)'s answer is the better way.

**Edit:**

About the quote you reference. In the same page notice:

> f may modify the elements of the range through the dereferenced
>   iterator

Answer (score 3):

Late answer, but noone has mentioned `std::transform`:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    A() = default;

    A& Add()
    {
        a++;
        return *this; // this will make it compatible with std::transform
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, A const& a)
    {
        return os << a.a;     
    }
private:
    int a;
};

int main()
{
    vector<A> x(10);
    std::transform(x.begin(), x.end(), x.begin(), [](auto& elem) { 
        return elem.Add(); 
    });
    std::copy(x.begin(), x.end(), std::ostream_iterator<A>(std::cout, ","));
}
```

[**Live Example.**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4f9206da104e82f1)

Note that I had to modify the return type of your `Add()` to `A&`. This makes it compatible with `std::transform`, and also mimics the return type of `operator++`.

Of course, a raw-loop with a single statement, or a `for_each` are fine as well. But `transform` is a **vocabulary** algorithm that immediately signifies to readers of your code that you are *modifying* the container. From a raw loop and `for_each`, this requires more careful scrutiny (trivial here perhaps, but in larger code these things add up). Notice e.g. the difference between

```
    std::transform(x.begin(), x.end(), x.begin(), [](auto& elem) { 
        // many lines but x will always be written to
    });

    std::for_each(x.begin(), x.end(), [](auto& elem) { 
        // many lines, will always need to inspect the code here 
        // to know if `elem` is actually being written to
        // the `auto&` is only a hint that this might happen
    });
```

Comment: Doesn't this end up with unnecessary copying?

Comment: @MateenUlhaq no, because `elem` is taken by-reference.

Comment: @TemplateRex: Yes, because `std::transform` will then take the `A&` returned by the lambda and assign it back into the range starting at `x.begin()`. Basically this is doing `elt = elt.Add();` for each `elt` in `x`, when all we needed was `elt.Add();` by itself. You're paying for each of those unnecessary `operator=` calls.